# OpenMP tasks in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openmp

I am trying to learn OMP library task based programming and as an example I copied and pasted the code below taken from a book and it outputs errors

```
 'task' : expected an OpenMP directive name
```

and

```
 'taskwait' : expected an OpenMP directive name
```

I can run omp parallel for loops but not tasks. Do you know whether omp tasking needs any further adjustments in visual studio?

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <omp.h>

 int fib(int n)
 {
   int i, j;
   if (n<2)
    return n;
 else
 {
   #pragma omp task shared(i) firstprivate(n)
   i=fib(n-1);

   #pragma omp task shared(j) firstprivate(n)
   j=fib(n-2);

   #pragma omp taskwait
   return i+j;
 }
 }

 int main()
{
  int n = 10;

  omp_set_dynamic(0);
  omp_set_num_threads(4);

  #pragma omp parallel shared(n)
  {
     #pragma omp single
     printf ("fib(%d) = %d\n", n, fib(n));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately, even Visual Studio 2019 still only supports [OpenMP 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/openmp-in-visual-cpp?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019), while Tasks were an [OpenMP 3.0 addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) and the [current standard](https://www.openmp.org/specifications/) at the time of writing is 5.0.