# OpenMP creates too many threads

Tags: c++, openmp

I am not sure why OpenMP uses so many threads. It seems to be not related to the Microsoft implementation because I have also tried the Intel library which shows the same behavior.
I have some parallel sections in my code which are compute bound and should not create and use more threads than I have cores. But what I have observed is that for n initiating threads OpenMP creates n*Cores threads. This looks like a big thread leak to me.

If I execute a "small" 32 bit application running on a server it can fail because 1000 OpenMP threads need 2 GB of address space already leaving no memory for the application. That should not happen. I would expect from an state of the art thread pool to reuse its threads and to take away no longer used threads.

I have tried to use omp_set_num_threads(8) to limit the thread pool size to 8 cores but that seems to only limit the number of threads per initiating thread instance. Am I doing all wrong or is OpenMP not to be meant to be used that way?

On my 8 core machine 5 started threads in my AsyncWorker class will allocate 38 threads created by OpenMP. I would expect only 8 threads to be created and these should be reused across all 5 initiating threads.

[image]

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <omp.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class AsyncWorker {
private:
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

public:
    AsyncWorker()
    {
    }

    void start() // add one thread that starts an OpenMP parallel section
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&AsyncWorker::threadFunc, this));
    }

    ~AsyncWorker()
    {
        for (auto &t : threads)
        {
            t.join();
        }
    }

private:
    void threadFunc()
    {
        std::atomic<int> counter;

        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::milliseconds durationInMs;

        while (durationInMs.count() <5000l) 
        {
        // each instance seems to get its own thread pool. 
        // Why? And how can I limit the threadpool to the number of cores and when will the threads be closed?
#pragma omp parallel  
            {
                counter++;
                auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                durationInMs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start);
            }
        }
    }

};

int main() {
    //omp_set_dynamic(0);
    //omp_set_nested(0);
    //omp_set_num_threads(8);

    {
        AsyncWorker foo;

        foo.start();  // 1
        foo.start();  // 2 
        foo.start();  // 3
        foo.start();  // 4
        foo.start();  // 5

        system("pause");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenMP is not meant to be used that way. Mixing OpenMP and other threading methods is a recipe for disaster unless done very carefully. And even then, the results are unpredictable. The OpenMP standard deliberately stays away from defining such kind of interoperability and the vendors are free to provide it the way they see fit (if they see fit).

`omp_set_num_threads(8)` does not do what you think it does. It sets the number of threads for parallel regions encountered by the current thread when no `num_threads()` clause is present. Also, `omp_set_nested(0)` has (or might have) no effect since you are not starting the parallel regions from OpenMP threads but rather from C++11 threads. Setting a global limit on the total number of OpenMP threads is possible via the `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT` environment variable, but that is only available in OpenMP 3.0 and later and MSVC is (forever?) stuck in the OpenMP 2.0 era.

Possible courses of action are:

- implement your own tasking for OpenMP 2.0 using a shared queue structure and OpenMP threads that spin in a loop dequeuing work items
- replace OpenMP with Intel [Threading Building Blocks](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) - it's open-source and supports various compilers on Windows, Linux, OS X, and Android
- replace OpenMP with Microsoft's PPL from the [Concurrency Runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207192.aspx), which basically provides a non-portable subset of TBB

Comment: So under which circumstances are the threads released? So far it looks like never. The initating threads do terminate and the associated threadpool continues to live happily. How am I supposed to manage resources on big boxes with hundreds of cores where this is really hurting the memory footprint because of thousands of allocated thread stacks. Is the design of OpenMP really that way that there must exist only one initiating thread of parallel actions? I cannot belive that C++ is still so far behind to support real multithreading.

Comment: I think I will go with set OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% to limit the number of OpenMP threads. That seems to be  a decent choice for CPU bound parallel operations which can potentially spawn multiple parallel operations at the same time.

Comment: By the way is it safe to use OMP_THREAD_LIMIT https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522775. According to Intel it could crash your process sometimes? "...If this limit is reached and another native operating system thread encounters OpenMP* API calls or constructs, the program can abort with an error message....". Does this mean I cannot safely limit the number of OpenMP threads?

Answer (score 3):

The number of threads OpenMP uses is set per parallel section, and you are concurrently spawning 5 parallel sections. Therefore you get 40 Threads.

It seems to be that you are looking for task based parallelism. In OpenMP you could achieve that by starting a parallel region and then creating tasks as needed. From the top of my head code for this pattern is written like this:

```
// Start parallel region
#pragma omp parallel
{
  // Only let a single thread create the tasks
  #pragma omp single
  {
     for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
     {
       // Actually create the task that needs to be performed
       #pragma omp task
       {
         heavy_work();
       }
     }
  }
}
```

This way you would only have 8 Threads working in parallel.

Comment: Unfortunately MS does not support tasks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545930/openmp-tasks-in-visual-studio. I can link to the Intel lib (libiomp5md.lib) but I have to enable in MSVC the OpenMP compiler support which will then complain with "C3001: 'task' : expected an OpenMP directive name". Otherwise I would need to recompile much of my code with the Intel C++ compiler.

Comment: @AloisKraus, mixing OpenMP and other threading methods is not officially supported. It is a grey area, so to say, and highly non-portable. On Windows, you'd better use Intel Threading Building Blocks (it should build with newer MSVC) or Microsoft's own [Concurrency Runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207192.aspx), which is quite similar to TBB.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I know Intel TBB but these rarely used due to the  high licensing cost for the Intel compiler. I would like to stick to a MSVC supported option so I need to look into CCR.

Comment: @AloisKraus, Intel TBB is open-source and it works with most modern C++ compilers. And unlike Microsoft's runtime, it also supports Linux and OS X.