# Memory leak in very simple code calling OpenMP in a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-leaks, openmp

This very simple code persistently consuming memory at a rate of about 1 MiB/sec.

```
// main.cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void omp_test() {
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    }
}

int main(int nArgCnt, char *ppArgs[]) {
    for (int i = 0; ; ++i) {
        std::thread proc(omp_test);
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        proc.join();
    }
}
```

Compiler: g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

Compile command:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -fopenmp
```

Run test:
./main

If I calling `omp_test()` in the for loop in `main` directly without `std::thread` or remove `omp parallel for`, no more memory leaks.

It seems like OpenMP left some unreleased memory at thread exit.

Comment: Mixing OpenMP with another threading mechanism, is not covered by the OpenMP specification and the behavior is consequently vendor-specific. You're alredy using OpenMP, I'd recommend removing std::thread altogether and making it standard compliant.

Comment: @E.N.D Thanks for your help. This sample code is extracted from our much bigger project. I must start a thread to serve each client and perform some computation parallel. If OpenMP can't be work with thread, I can only use the thread pool to implement the parallel computation.

Comment: What happens if you monitor threads count of the process? I would expect it to spawn more and more new threads?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37391492/126995

Comment: @Snoots No, it doesn't spawn more threads. The total number of threads is always 9 (NLWP by `htop`), but the memory is continuously consumed. Thanks for your information.

Comment: an alternative way is create a omp task and then use the parallel for. you must activate nested parallelism for this.